# D3: clustered force layout with fixed centers

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the image below
[example http://www.magora-systems.com/media/good.png](http://www.magora-systems.com/media/good.png)
which I found on this [page](http://www.magora-systems.com/how-to-build-a-bubble-chart-with-using-d3-js/). The author gives some explanation on how he does this, using a clustered force technique from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658, but not enough for me to fully understand it

What I do not know is how to set the centers of each cluster to a predefined location (where I define these center locations in a variable for example)?

My second, but less important question is about an extra feature that is mentioned on the blog where I found the image: "it’s been decided that a bubble with the largest diameter in a group will become central". 
Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Googling "d3 force layout multiple foci" brings up several examples that might be helpful.  [This one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021953) provides a very simple illustration, but you might want to look at the others for other techniques that could be useful given your goal.

Comment: Thank you! That seems like an example I can use, I guess I was just googling the wrong words :)

Comment: Is there also a way to make the nodes oblivious to the repulsion of nodes in other groups? From the example you gave, the nodes in different groups start to repel each other, but it seems like this is not the case in the image above

Comment: Yes, sometimes that's the hard part--figuring out the right search terms.  I don't have any advice about the repulsion issue.  It might have to do with tuning the force layout parameters.  [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1249681) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting cluster view that I haven't seen before with D3, thanks for that. I looked at the pages you linked, and the author describes a guide found [here](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_in_d3.html).

The Grants by Year tab for the example puts 3 clusters organized by year. The example code is calling vis.coffee and defining the year center locations like this :

```
@year_centers = {
  "2008": {x: @width / 3, y: @height / 2},
  "2009": {x: @width / 2, y: @height / 2},
  "2010": {x: 2 * @width / 3, y: @height / 2}
}
```

And I see a method for moving the circles to their year_centers like this:

```
# move all circles to their associated @year_centers 
  move_towards_year: (alpha) =>
    (d) =>
      target = @year_centers[d.year]
      d.x = d.x + (target.x - d.x) * (@damper + 0.02) * alpha * 1.1
      d.y = d.y + (target.y - d.y) * (@damper + 0.02) * alpha * 1.1
```

You may want to poke around in the vis.coffee or vis.js files, but the vis.coffee file is the one referenced with the source example.